# Flutter como hacer el builder con el widget ListWheelScrollView

Tags: flutter

como andan?

Tenia en mi app un listView, pero hace poco vi el widget ListWheelScrollView y no dude en pasarlo a él.

Es una lista de negocios que se traen de la base de datos en json.

Para la lista, tenia el siguiente codigo:

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.length,  //DONDE snapshot trae toda la info.
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  Negocio negocio = snapshot.data[index]; //INSTANCIAMOS LA LISTA NEGOCIO
                  return NegocioItem(negocio: negocio);
                });
```

Bien, el problema que se me presento es como paso esto al widget ListWheelScrollView.

Por el momento solamente tengo:

```
body: FutureBuilder<List<Negocio>>(
        future: list,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {

            Negocio negocio = snapshot.data[!!ACA DEBERIA DE IR EL INDEX];
            return ListWheelScrollView(
              itemExtent: 200,
              children: <Widget>[
                   NegocioItem(negocio: negocio),
              ],

            );
                ## Título ##
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            //return pantalla_sindatos();
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner
          return Center(
            child: ColorLoader3(
              radius: 20.0,
              dotRadius: 5.0,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

No se como "construir" el index, para pasar cada elemento de la lista.

por las dudas dejo mi clase NegocioItem:

```
class NegocioItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @required
  final Negocio negocio;
  NegocioItem({this.negocio});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Image.network(
                  negocio.imageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                negocio.title,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              Text(
                negocio.horario,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: getColor(negocio.horario),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
      },
    );
  }
}
```

muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, ya que tienes el snapshot con los datos, que es un Listado de Negocios, puedes usar el método `map` para transformar los elementos a tu widget `NegocioItem`, de la siguiente manera:

```dart
  if (snapshot.hasData) {

            return ListWheelScrollView(
              itemExtent: 250,
              children: 
               snapshot.data.map((item) =>  NegocioItem(negocio: item)).toList()
            );

          }
```

**EDIT**

Por algún motivo `ListWheelScrollView` no funciona bien con `Card` widget, así que elimina ese widget de `NegocioItem`, tampoco podrás usar `GestureDetector` ya que `ListWheelScrollView` absorbe los touchs, en lugar de eso implementa el método `onSelectedItemChanged`.

```
ListWheelScrollView(
              itemExtent: 250,
               onSelectedItemChanged: (index){
                    print("iNDEX: $index");
                  },
...
```

Comment: Hola diego! Gracias por tu aporte, ahora si pude visualizar, pero solamente un dato.

Comment: hice un  print(snapshot.data.length); y me imprime 2. pero solamente me muestra un solo dato, que puede ser?

Comment: Al itemExtent lo cambie por el valor 250, ya que si le pongo el length de snapshot le da un  valor de 2 y no se ve, ya que este le da el tamaño

Comment: Cierto, mi error, ese ea el tamño del elemento, ya no necesitas especificar la longitud de elementos porque ya viene implicito en el children

Comment: No pasa nada diego, sigo viendo xq el map recorre solamente una vez

Comment: Puedes poner una imagen de como se ve, en tu pregunta? Verifica q no hay error en el log

Comment: ya edito la publicacion, no hay ningun error en el log

Comment: Disculpa la hora, ya edite la publi

Comment: No scrolea? Estas segura que tienes 2 items? A negocioitem GestureDetector , encima ponle un SizedBox con un tamaño

Comment: No scrolea, ni horizonal ni vertical. Si tiene dos items, hice dos prints, uno en la clase Negocio cuando me trae de la base de datos `List jsonList = jsonObject["negocio"];
    print(jsonList);`

Comment: y el otro print al snapshot.data.lenght y devuelve 2

Comment: encima le puse un SizedBox, con un valor de 200 x 200 px. y solamente achico el card. No aparecio nada mas. Tampoco funciona el metodo OnTap de la clase NegocioItem, yo en la publicacioon no lo puse, pero te redicciona a otra pantalla

Comment: Dentro del children puede ir un .toList() ?

Comment: Muy extraño, si tienes el repository donde este tu codigo para ayudarte

Comment: https://github.com/emiibarra6/viviguamini/blob/Bloc/lib/negocio/ui/screen/lista_negocios.dart

Comment: ok ahora puedes indicar como entrar a ese flujo ? hay datos? como puedo probar?

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: Gracias x la info Diego!